# Oozie workflow to run different set of tables in parallel

Tags: oozie

I have 3 different set of tables. 1st set contains 3 tables, 2nd set contains 4 tables and 3rd set contains 5 tables. Now I want all these 3 sets should start in parallel (independent of each other) in an Oozie workflow.

Can anyone suggest a sample workflow for the same.

```
set1         set2                set3
Job11        job21               job31
job12        job22               job32
job13        job23               job33
             job24               job34
                                 job35
```

I want a workflow setup in such a way that if any job fails as part of any for any one set, then I want the other sets to continue and shouldn't fail or wait because of the failed set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fork and Join control nodes from Oozie workflow. If you want to execute actions for all the tables in parallel, write action for each table and add them into the Fork node OR If you want to parallelize it set basis, you can do it that way.

Sample Workflow from Apache Oozie Documentation:

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    ...
    <fork name="[FORK-NODE-NAME]">
        <path start="[NODE-NAME]" />
        ...
        <path start="[NODE-NAME]" />
    </fork>
    ...
    <join name="[JOIN-NODE-NAME]" to="[NODE-NAME]" />
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

You can find more information here: [Fork and Join Control Nodes](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes)

Comment: I want a workflow setup in such a way that if any job fails as part of any for any one set, then I want the other sets to continue and shouldn't fail or wait because of the failed set.

Comment: I would suggest you to give try by yourself and come back if you have any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create 3 separate workflows and set both the
`<error to="">` and `<ok to="">` parameter of each job action to the next job, simply ignoring any errors and moving through the jobs.

To get the workflows to run in parallel you can use the fork as specified here: [Oozie fork specification](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.5_Fork_and_Join_Control_Nodes) or if you have Falcon installed simply make 3 Falcon processes that are scheduled at the same time. This should provide you with the functionality you need.

The only issue with this is that you have no way of really tracking whether any of the jobs failed or not.